# How to publish with GeckoFx

Tags: c#, publish, geckofx

so I'm using the latest version of geckofx, and I need to publish my app now with all dlls embedded in my exe making me able to execute it on my desktop(not via shortcut). I already searched a lot for geckofx publish but so far I haven't found anything that works for me. Made all dlls from the auto created folder named "Firefox" Embedded already and my omni.ja as content. But the app doesn't oppen still. Anyone that works or worked with geckofx know how to make this possible?

tl;dr - Make single exe with all dlls embedded using GeckoFx.

Thanks for all the help, sorry for any grammar mistake.

Edit: Added my folder and my Firefox folder: [Project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp1eK.png) [Firefox folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFnsh.png)

All Dlls are like this: [Dlls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvfnn.png).

And when I try to run the app in the desktop after rebuild the solution show this error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikL2s.png).

And if I publish the app doesn't start at all eventhough the size of the exe is getting bigger which I expect the dlls are getting embedded(?).

Comment: Why don't you write all dlls in the app folder when execute it ?

Comment: @Kaj what do you mean? Paste all the files from my so called "Firefox" folder to my project folder or debug folder??

Comment: Please see the SetUpXulRunner() method here: https://github.com/BloomBooks/BloomDesktop/blob/master/src/BloomExe/Browser.cs

Comment: @JohnHatton it's still giving me the same error message that xul.dll is missing, even thought it's embedded..